# Correctly exporting shape keys in blender

Tags: json, three.js, blender

I want to export shape keys in blender but the morph target array in the exported json file has array inside an array. I want all the shape keys points to be inside a single array. Any tips on how to export the shape keys correctly.

Screenshot of my exported json file.(https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6wLPPFE11zoWWNvQy1YbFNXblU)

I want the morphTarget array be like what it is in this knight example (http://threejs.org/examples/models/skinned/knight.js). I want all the points to come inside a single array.

I am using blender 2.76 and io_three expoter.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is correct even though it is misleading. The confusion comes from two different types of data stored using the same data block name.

Each morphTarget contains an array referenced as "vertices"

One type of data is the locations of each vertex. This is what you see in the knight example. Each coordinate for each vertex is included in the array, which is the actual vertex location for each frame. The morphTargets for this will have names like "animation_000000", "animation_000001"...

```
"morphTargets":[{
    "name":"animation_000000",
    "vertices":[-1,-1,1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,1,
      1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1]
},{
    "name":"animation_000001",
    "vertices":[-1.0149,-1.0149,1.0149,-1.0149,1.0149,1.0149,
      -1.0149,-1.0149,-1.0149,-1.0149,1.0149,-1.0149,1.0149,
      -1.0149,1.0149,1.0149,1.0149,1.0149,1.0149,-1.0149,-1.0149,
      1.0149,1.0149,-1.0149]
},{ ....
```

To get this animation data you need to export with "Apply Modifiers" enabled and "Blend Shape animation" disabled.

[image: export settings for animation data]

The other type of data is an array of vectors that constitute the shapekey data, so you get an array containing arrays of 3 numbers. A shapekey in blender is a collection of vectors defining the vertex movement relative to the original position and this appears to be what is exported here. The morphTarget names for this data match the shapekey names used, by default that is "Key 1", "Key 2"...

```
"morphTargets":[{
    "name":"Key 1",
    "vertices":[[-1.01209,-1.17045,-1.09497],[-1.10082,-1.09175,1.09065],
      [-1.085,1.01564,-1.17664],[-1.17373,1.09434,1.00897],
      [1.17373,-1.09434,-1.00897],[1.085,-1.01564,1.17664],
      [1.10082,1.09175,-1.09065],[1.01209,1.17045,1.09497]]
},{
    "name":"Key 2",
    "vertices":[[-1.49369,-1.20168,-1.4188],[-1.47777,-1.31454,1.33278],
      [-1.26675,1.54064,-1.30763],[-1.25083,1.42778,1.44395],
      [1.25083,-1.42778,-1.44395],[1.26675,-1.54064,1.30763],
      [1.47777,1.31454,-1.33278],[1.49369,1.20168,1.4188]]
}],
```

To get the shapekey data in the export you need to enable "Blend Shape animation" and disable "Apply Modifiers". This export doesn't seem to include any keyframed animation relating to the shapekeys.

[image: export settings for shapekey data]

Comment: problem that i am facing is that list of vertices are in the form of array within an array. Here is a screenshot of the json file https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6wLPPFE11zoWWNvQy1YbFNXblU Thank you

Comment: A bit of exploring finds the difference between the two data types, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot that was really helpful. But i was wondering how they got the morphtagets in this example (http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_morphtargets_human) here all the vertices are inside a single array without using any animation. Thank you once again